# How to disable changelist indicator for new changes

Tags: intellij-idea

Since i connected my project with github this annoying indicator next to my code shows up whenever i make a change in my project. I looked for answers but did not find one. Is there any way to disable this?

[Annoying_green_indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6NKS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Preferences | Editor | General and disable "Highlight modified lines in the gutter"